# Why do I fail to encode back a decoded JWT?

Tags: java, authentication, jwt

I have this JWT token:

```
public final String WTOK = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwdWIiOiIyMzUzNiIsIndpZCI6IjAwMXcwMDAwMDFmbEN3MkFBRV9NMTQ0NDU5IiwidXJsIjpbIndvY2hpdC5jb20iXSwiZXhwaXJ5IjoiMjAyMy0wMy0yOFQxMjoxMToyNC4xODdaIiwiaWF0IjoxNjQ4NDY5NDg0fQ.r_xKkhqE2WCmqcrsdFvZsMFbWDoaV9AVGrg8pq270ZE";
```

Then I used the following simple method to decode it:

```
public class DecodedToken {

    Map<String, Object> headers;
    String payload;
    String signature;
}

private DecodedToken decodeToken(String token) {

    String[] chunks = token.split("\\.");

    Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getUrlDecoder();

    try {
        String headersStr = new String(decoder.decode(chunks[0]));
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> headers = objectMapper.readValue(headersStr, Map.class);
        String payload = new String(decoder.decode(chunks[1]));
        System.out.println(payload);
        String signature = new String(decoder.decode(chunks[2]));
        System.out.println(signature);

        return new DecodedToken(headers, payload, signature);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and the parts where decoded successfully.

Then I tried to encode it back using the following method:

```
private String encodeToken( DecodedToken decodedToken) {

    byte[] decodedSecret = Base64.getDecoder().decode(SECRET_KEY_BASE64);
    byte[] encodedSignature = Base64.getEncoder().encode(decodedToken.getSignature().getBytes());
    System.out.println(new String(encodedSignature));

    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("alg", decodedToken.getHeaders().get("alg"));
    headers.put("typ", decodedToken.getHeaders().get("typ"));

    return Jwts.builder()
        .setPayload(decodedToken.getPayload())
        .setHeader(headers)
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,decodedSecret)
        .compact();
}
```

which returned me a string.
However, the signature part came out different from the original one.

Can you advise what is wrong with my code?
My guess I should encode back the decoded signature. How can I do that?

(Please tell me if you need more information from me)

---

Update

I retried the methods above with a token I created by myself and a my secret key.

Would you please use them on my code and try to see where is the error?

> token:
> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwdWIiOiJwdWJwdWIiLCJ3aWQiOiJ3aWR3aWQiLCJleHBpcnkiOiIyMDIzLTAzLTMwVDE2OjExOjAwWiIsInVybCI6WyJsbCJdfQ.o8qD7CfvtWFvqE-Ti_hZq2Tcf4tdcIWutr6vFNRtwRw
>
> Base64 secret key: MTIzNDU2NDU2NDMyMTMyMTY1NDY1ODc4OTc5NjQxMzIx
>
> headers:
>
> {   "alg": "HS256",   "typ": "JWT" }
>
> enc: A128CBC-HS256

Comment: this should only work if everything is identical to original actions that were done when encoding the JWT. Is it so, do you know how the JWT was created?

Comment: `new String(decoder.decode(chunks[0]), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`? `String` can hold text, but not binary data. Conversion from bytes always involve some Charset, possibly corrupting data. _(No remembered experience with JwtBuilder.)_

Comment: @JoopEggen Sorry, can't follow you... Where did you see StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ? Or do you suggest me to use it? thanks

Comment: @eis I know the secret key. Anyway the problem is only the difference in the signature.

Comment: I see now two very different tokens in your question. It would be interesting to see the original token and the rebuilt token  side by side to compare.

Comment: @jps Do you refer to the new token I posted in the update? This is my own test as opposed to the original data which was given to me.

Comment: what I mean is: you decode a token and encode it again and wonder about the different signatures, right?! So it would be useful to see the token that you decode (original) and the result of you encoding. Then it's easier to see if there's additional whitespace, different order of values etc.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that `new String(byte[])` uses the default platform encoding which is non-portable and not all bytes are _text_, some are binary data (payload) which might be corrupted. You said the strings were alrlght, but if the dev pc is Windows, the server Linux, you might want to use `new String(byte[], Charset)` or better keep the `byte[]`.

Comment: @dushkin I didn't say it's only about the secret key. you would need to know all the exact parameters and options that were used when making this JWT, including signature. without it, it's not likely you would get identical result.

Comment: @jps Got it now. Will do

Comment: @JoopEggen The decoding was ok for the textual values of course. I don't know if the signature was decoded correctly, and according to what you've said - probably it wasn't. I'll check your recommendation. Thanks

Comment: @eis Understood now

Answer (score 1):

The resulting signature can be different even for the same payload and headers. It depends also on whitespace, newline, etc. characters used. Maybe the original token was formatted with whitespaces, that were removed in the resulting string?

Also, remember that the signature is calculated for payload **and** header. I can see that you're constructing the header yourself. Is it exactly the same as in the original?

Comment: Yes, the headers are the same. Ignoring the data, does the algorithm looks valid?

Comment: Yeah, it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to solve the problem:

```
private String encodeToken(DecodedToken decodedToken) {

        Key hmacKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(SECRET_KEY_BASE64),
            SignatureAlgorithm.HS256.getJcaName());

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> payload = objectMapper.readValue(decodedToken.getPayload(), Map.class);

        return Jwts.builder()
            .setHeaderParam("alg", decodedToken.getHeaders().get("alg"))
            .setHeaderParam("typ", decodedToken.getHeaders().get("typ"))
            .claim("pub", payload.get("pub"))
            .claim("wid", payload.get("wid"))
            .claim("expiry", payload.get("expiry"))
            .claim("url", payload.get("url"))
            .signWith(hmacKey)
            .compact();
}
```

With this I got the same jwt back.
Another matter that wasted my time was that at the beggining I set the headers with this order:

```
.setHeaderParam("typ", decodedToken.getHeaders().get("typ"))
.setHeaderParam("alg", decodedToken.getHeaders().get("alg"))
```

whereas as I should have set them with this order:

```
.setHeaderParam("alg", decodedToken.getHeaders().get("alg"))
.setHeaderParam("typ", decodedToken.getHeaders().get("typ"))
```

That was creating a different signature... :(

Thank you all!!